# how to use filterControl: 'select' with formatter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table for working with data from my database.
I get my data in javascript and I wanted to filter by select and I have a formatter on each column
I tried some solutions but nothing worked.

[exemple the filter of reglementation is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiWLS.png)

what do you think ?

My code

```
let defaultColumns = [{
            field: 'id',
            title: 'ID',
            filterControl: "input",
            visible: false
        }, {
            field: 'article',
            title: 'Article N°',
            filterType: 'input',
            height: 1700,
            filterControl: "input",
            formatter: initialiseSelect,

        }, {
            field: 'reglementation',
            title: 'Réglementation',
            searchable: 'true',
            filterControl: 'select',
            filterData: 'var:arrayReg',
            formatter: initialiseSelectReglementation,

        },  {
            field: 'action',
            title: 'Valider',
            filterControl: "select",
            filterData: 'var:arrayReg',
            height: 700,
            formatter: initialiseCheckbox,
        }

        ];
```

to initialize the array

```
let options = {
                    url: ******,
                    method: 'GET',
                    locale: "fr-FR",
                    uniqueId: "id",
                    pagination: true,
                    showExport: true,
                    filterControl: true,
                    disableUnusedSelectOptions: true,
                    // showRefresh: true,
                    autoRefresh: true,
                    exportDataType: "all",
                    exportTypes: ['csv', 'excel'],
                    columns: defaultColumns,
                };
                //initialisation de table

                initTable(options);
```